# Trigger a job by another successful Jenkins job while two Jenkins are located on different instances

Tags: jenkins, triggers, jenkins-job-dsl

I have two Jenkins that are located on a different instances, I want to trigger Job 'A' on Jenkins 'A', after a job 'B' finished running and succeeded on Jenkins 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to add a webhook for a Job 'A' on Jenkins 'A' that starts the job, and let job 'B' on Jenkins 'B' trigger this webhook.

This [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin) might be helpful with this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins API to trigger the job on another instance, please see the below API

```
curl -X POST --user user:password http://JenkinsA:8080/jenkins/job/A/build
```

You can have a condition if Jenkins "**B**" job is successfully run the above API.

Comment: Ok but where exactly should I use the Curl command? @user_9090

Comment: you can add it to a stage in jenkins file or add it any script which you are executing